# TCP socket continuously returns EAGAIN

Tags: tcp, recv

In my testing, I found that when i send packets of bytes 1000-5000 bytes from my sender, they get assembled/bundled at receiver with sizes 8000-14000 bytes. I checked the wireshark capture to confirm this.

I have 2 questions:
1) Who bundles these packets in between, receiver receives these and I use select() to detect data and call recvmsg api ?.

2) When packets of lengths increase at receiver, I implemented partial reception so that 'recvmsg' returns partial data also. In this case after some time, recvmsg call returns EAGAIN with 0 bytes. 
The connection with peer is still up, because peer is still sending packets, why is recvmsg call returing error with EAGAIN ?.

Please help !

Comment: You must be in non-blocking mode. Solution:d on't be, or use select().

Comment: I already use select() to get notified for data..my receiver is able to receive data for some time, but as large bytes comein, the recvmsg calls returns o bytes.

Comment: It should never do that if select() has indicated that the channel is readable. Your description doesn't make sense. If recv() returns -1 with errno set to EAGAIN it isn't also giving you zero bytes at the same time. It can't return zero *and* -1. If you get EAGAIN it just means there is nothing to read and you have to re-select.

Comment: Thanks..But I am pretty sure that during high load this issue happens. Yes, it is returning 0 bytes but the socket buffer has still data left. I use ioctl to trace data in recv buffer and call recvmsg for which it returns EAGAIN.. Is there any possibility that if mesg size in recv buffer exceeds some limit and then this issue comes//

Comment: I get EAGAIN only when data in recv buffer increases some limit, i guess its aroung 32767. As i said i use ioctl to calculate recv buffer size and then use help of 'recvmsg' which returns EAGAIN. This happens on high load..for small data packets the flow works fine/

Comment: 1st as select tells that there is data on the socket, i use the ioctl call     ret = ioctl(sockFd->fd, FIONREAD, dataLen); to find dataLength.        Then i use a while loop while(dataLen >0) {          recvLen = recvmsg(sockFd->fd, &msg, flags);
         if ((recvLen == INET_ERR) then I check the error code else process. I cannot paste the whole code because I have many other things involved..Sorry

Comment: Hi Manish, did you solve this issue? I am facing a similar situation. Your help will be appreciated. Here is the link to the question i posted. http://askubuntu.com/questions/790434/lan-to-lan-communication-not-working-while-internet-works-fine-ubuntu-16-04-lt

Answer (score 0):

> I found that when i send packets of bytes 1000-5000 bytes from my sender, they get assembled/bundled at receiver with sizes 8000-14000 bytes
>
> 1) Who bundles these packets in between, receiver receives these and I use select() to detect data and call recvmsg api?.

If those are Ethernet packets of size 9000 bytes then you must be using [jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame).

TCP is a stream, there is no concept of a message. Data sent in multiple `send()` calls may be received in one `recv()` call and vice versa.

> 2) When packets of lengths increase at receiver, I implemented partial reception so that 'recvmsg' returns partial data also. In this case after some time, recvmsg call returns EAGAIN with 0 bytes. The connection with peer is still up, because peer is still sending packets, why is recvmsg call returing error with EAGAIN ?.

It means you are using non-blocking sockets and no more data is available in the socket receive buffer. In this case you should use `select/poll/epoll` to wait on one or more sockets until more data is available for reading.

Comment: I have data available on the receiver socket, as I use a ioctl call to check the data length in the recv socket buffer. Select returns asking me to read from this socket and then when I read it recvmsg returns EAGAIN. This works for small data packets, but when the length at recv buffer increases some limit, i face this issue.